# Check if column 1 value appeared previously in dataset with a different column 2 value

Tags: r

I have my dataset such that

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("m1","m2","m3","m4","m5","m6","m2","m3","m5","m6","m1","m4","m5"),
                 Year = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3))
```

and want to perform a check whether the ID appears in the previous year. Now I have a code that seems to work

```
df$Check <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x["ID"] %in% df[df$Year == (as.numeric(x["Year"]) - 1), "ID"])
```

but given that my dataset is 3million rows long this function takes far too long to run. Is there a better alternative to this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
dfs <- split(df$ID, df$Year);
df$check <- unlist(mapply(`%in%`, dfs,  lag(dfs)))
```

Comment: Cheers, works great! Just requires the dataset to be ordered by year beforehand

Comment: @Gowzie Yes, you need `df <- arrange(df, Year)` beforehand. Let me know how it worked out for your real data.

Answer (score 1):

```
k = length(unique(df$Year))        # how many years in the data
q = unique(df$Year)                # which are the years present

func <- function(x){  
  kk = df$ID[df$Year == q[x]]      # get the current year's ID which are present
  kk %in% df$ID[df$Year == q[x-1]] # compare that to the previous year's ID
}

x <- sum(df$Year==unique(df$Year)[1]) #to know how many FALSE to be added initially
df$check <- c(rep(FALSE, x),unlist(lapply(2:k, func)))
```

Comment: did it help you @Gowzie ?

Comment: Unfortunately getting the error of the "replacement has 20 rows, data has 13" and haven't had time to look in to how to resolve this. But since @ExperimenteR solution worked so well I'm currently using his.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ave`: for each `ID`, calculate the difference between current `Year` and preceeding `Year` (`diff`). Pad with a leading zero. Check if the result is `1` to create a logical vector:

```
df$check2 <- with(df, ave(Year, ID, FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x))) == 1)
#    ID Year check check2
# 1  m1    1 FALSE  FALSE
# 2  m2    1 FALSE  FALSE
# 3  m3    1 FALSE  FALSE
# 4  m4    1 FALSE  FALSE
# 5  m5    1 FALSE  FALSE
# 6  m6    1 FALSE  FALSE
# 7  m2    2  TRUE   TRUE
# 8  m3    2  TRUE   TRUE
# 9  m5    2  TRUE   TRUE
# 10 m6    2  TRUE   TRUE
# 11 m1    3 FALSE  FALSE
# 12 m4    3 FALSE  FALSE
# 13 m5    3  TRUE   TRUE
```

Similar with `data.table`:

For each `ID` (`by = ID`), create the new variable `check2`: check if the difference between current `Year` and preceeding `Year` in the data is `1` ((`diff(year) == 1`), i.e. if the preceeding year is the *previous* year.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , Check2 := c(FALSE, diff(Year) == 1), by = ID]
```

---

Edit following comment by OP. In case of "*multiple entries of the same ID in the same year*", you perform the calulation on data where duplicated rows are removed (`unique`). Then join the result to the original data.

```
df2 <- unique(df)
df2[ , Check2 := c(FALSE, diff(Year) == 1), by = ID]
df[df2, on = c("ID", "Year")]
```

Comment: Good alternative, but fails when you have multiple entries of the same ID in the same year. Definitely easy to work around and a hell of a lot quicker than my original solution!

Comment: @Gowzie Thanks for your feedback. Please remember to always construct an examples in your question which has sufficient complexity. We are not mind readers...;)